# Redirect verbose stream from remote session in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I want to save the verbose output from remote session into a variable or file

only the normal output can be redirect, but not the verbose output.

```
$VerbosePreference = "Continue"

$s = New-PSSession localhost
$str = (Invoke-Command -Session $s -Verbose -Script {
    $VerbosePreference = "Continue"
    "1"
    Write-Verbose "2"
} *>&1)

"str=$str"
```

Expected output:

```
str=1 2
```

Actual output:

```
VERBOSE: 2
str=1
```

Answer (score 0):

Redirect the verbose output *inside* the scriptblock. Use either

```
$s = New-PSSession -ComputerName localhost
$str = Invoke-Command -Verbose -Session $s -ScriptBlock {
    "1"
    Write-Verbose "2" -Verbose 4>&1
}
"str=$str"
```

or even

```
$s = New-PSSession -ComputerName localhost
$str = Invoke-Command -Verbose -Session $s -ScriptBlock {
    $(
        "1"
        Write-Verbose "2" -Verbose
    ) *>&1
}
"str=$str"
```

Nothe that above code snippets work as expected with *default* verbose preference i.e. `$VerbosePreference = 'SilentlyContinue'`.

Comment: your solution need to change all the Invoke-Command, what I need to do is redirect a script file which has multiple Invoke_command on remote sessions. like:
.\scriptWithRemoteCommand.ps1 *>&1 | out-file .\mylog.txt

I found that the Write-Information has no this issue, but not for Write-Verbose